# How to properly handle timezone when passing POSIXct objects between R and Postgres DBMS?

Tags: r, posixct, rpostgresql

I am struggling to understand what exactly happens behind the scenes when passing `POSIXct` objects between R and Postgres using `RPostgreSQL`. In the following example, I define two timestamp fields: one *with* a timezone the other one *without*. However, it appears that they are treated exactly the same when passing `POSIXct` objects via `dbWriteTable` and `dbReadTable`.

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432", user= "postgres",
                 dbname = "test_db")

q <- "
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
  dttm timestamp without time zone,
  dttmtz timestamp with time zone
)"
dbSendQuery(con, q)

# using timezone CET
dttm <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 10:20:10", tz="CET")
df <- data.frame(dttm = dttm, dttmtz = dttm)
dbWriteTable(con, "test_table", df, overwrite=FALSE, append=T, row.names=0)

# using timezone UTC    
dttm <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 14:20:10", tz="UTC")
df <- data.frame(dttm = dttm, dttmtz = dttm)
dbWriteTable(con, "test_table", df, overwrite=FALSE, append=T, row.names=0)

df2 <- dbReadTable(con, "test_table")
```

Both fields come out exactly the same. It appears as if the timezones are completely discarded.

```
df2$dttm
[1] "2016-01-01 10:20:10 CET" "2016-01-01 14:20:10 CET"

df2$dttmtz
"2016-01-01 10:20:10 CET" "2016-01-01 14:20:10 CET"
```

**QUESTIONS:**

1. What exactly goes on behind the scenes?
2. How can I properly pass the POSIXct's timezone back and forth?

Answer (score 2):

I think you've pointed out a bug in RPostgreSQL: it does not seem to be getting time zone from R for POSIXct objects. Timezone information can be passed correctly to PostgreSQL by formatting timestamps as character with offset from UTC (see example at bottom of this answer; added 2018-09-21). But first, here's an illustration of the apparent bug:

Modifying your code:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv,  port = "5432", user= "postgres",
                 dbname = "test")

# timestamps in three different time zones
dt1 <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 10:20:10", tz="US/Eastern")
dt2 <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 10:20:10", tz="UTC")
dt3 <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 10:20:10", tz="Asia/Tokyo")
df <- data.frame(dt1=dt1, dt2=dt2, dt3=dt3)

q <- "
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
  dt1 timestamp with time zone,
  dt2 timestamp with time zone,
  dt3 timestamp with time zone,
  PRIMARY KEY (dt1)
)"
dbSendQuery(con, q)

dbWriteTable(con, "test_table", df, overwrite=FALSE, append=T, row.names=0)

df2 <- dbReadTable(con, "test_table")
```

note that all three timestamps are equal
timezones not handled correctly

```
df2$dt1
```

"2016-01-01 10:20:10 EST"

```
df2$dt2
```

"2016-01-01 10:20:10 EST"

```
df2$dt3
```

"2016-01-01 10:20:10 EST"

And same is true in postgres
- as seen in pgadmin here 
[image]

**This suggests postgres is not getting timezone from R**

Note that if we manually change one time zone in test_table
(e.g., first record in pgadmin)

eg, 
[image]

and fetch

```
df2 <- dbReadTable(con, "test_table")
```

then the timezone is correctly handled

```
df2$dt1
```

"2016-01-01 05:20:10 EST"

```
df2$dt2
```

"2016-01-01 10:20:10 EST"

```
df2$dt3
```

"2016-01-01 10:20:10 EST"

**So this suggets that RPostgreSQL is *not* correctly passing time zone information to postgres** but that RPostgreSQL is correctly getting time zone information from postgres.

---

## ***answer to the original question***

**To  pass a timestamp with timezone from R to Postgres using RPostgreSQL**, just format it as a character string with the offset from UTC (e.g., "2016-01-01 10:20:10-0500"; e.g., use `format` and then pass it to Postgres, same as above.

E.g.:

```
#convert POSIXct to character with offset from UTC
df$dt1 <- format(df$dt1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS%z")
df$dt2 <- format(df$dt2, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS%z")
df$dt3 <- format(df$dt3, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS%z")

##> df
##                       dt1                      dt2                      dt3
##1 2016-01-01 10:20:10-0500 2016-01-01 10:20:10+0000 2016-01-01 10:20:10+0900

q <- "
CREATE TABLE test_table2
(
  dt1 timestamp with time zone,
  dt2 timestamp with time zone,
  dt3 timestamp with time zone,
  PRIMARY KEY (dt1)
)"
dbSendQuery(con, q)

dbWriteTable(con, "test_table2", df, overwrite=FALSE, append=T, row.names=0)

df3 <- dbReadTable(con, "test_table2")

#Note that times are now correct (in local time zone)
##> df3$dt1
##[1] "2016-01-01 10:20:10 EST"
##> df3$dt2
##[1] "2016-01-01 05:20:10 EST"
##> df3$dt3
##[1] "2015-12-31 20:20:10 EST"
```

Comment: revisiting this today, I noticed that the question (how to correctly pass timestamps with timezone to postgres) was not answered, so I added it (e.g., pass as character string with offset from UTC).

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say that I am not a fan of the way R handles this. Let's take a value of time in UTC:

```
dttm.utc <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 10:20:10", tz="UTC")
dttm.utc
[1] "2016-01-01 10:20:10 UTC"
```

Now we *can* convert it to CET timezone relatively easily:

```
dttm.cet <- format( dttm.utc, tz = "CET", usetz = T )
dttm.cet
[1] "2016-01-01 11:20:10 CET"
```

But check this out, each of those values is of a different class. The first is in a `POSIX` format, but the second has been converted to `character` class by the `format` function.

```
class( dttm.utc )
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

class( dttm.cet )
[1] "character"
```

That's no good, because it means we can't just do the same conversion again in the other direction, we need to first convert the latter value to `POSIX` class first, being very careful not to let R muck around with the timezone:

```
dttm.cet <- as.POSIXct( dttm.cet, tz = "CET" )
dttm.cet
[1] "2016-01-01 11:20:10 CET"

class( dttm.cet )
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Now we can convert it:

```
format( dttm.cet, tz = "UTC", usetz = TRUE )
[1] "2016-01-01 10:20:10 UTC"
```

But that puts us back to `character` class. Very annoying. Here's a workaround. Build the two-step conversion into a function, and use that from now on.

```
convert.tz <- function( x, tz ) {
    new <- format( x, tz = tz, usetz = T )
    return( as.POSIXct( new, tz = tz ) )
}
```

Give that a try:

```
dttm.utc <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 10:20:10", tz="UTC")
dttm.utc
[1] "2016-01-01 10:20:10 UTC"

dttm.cet <- convert.tz( dttm.utc, "CET" )
dttm.cet
[1] "2016-01-01 11:20:10 CET"

class( dttm.utc )
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

class( dttm.cet )
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

So now the conversion doesn't change the format, which means we can go either way in the conversion, without changing the method:

```
convert.tz( dttm.cet, "UTC" )
[1] "2016-01-01 10:20:10 UTC"
```

Ahhh. Much better.

Of course, you could stick with base R, and do this every time you convert.

```
dttm.cet <- as.POSIXct( format( dttm.utc, tz = "CET", usetz = T ), tz = "CET" )
```

But personally, I like the function a lot better.

Comment: Thank rosscova. However, I am not sure if you address my question which concerns passing datetimes between R and Postgres, not just changing the timezone of a POSIXct object. For the latter there are functions available, e.g. `lubridate::with_tz(dttm.utc, "CET")`. So no need to write another wrapper.

Comment: Right, sorry. I figured the issue you're having was with the R conversion itself. Doesn't solving the R tz conversion problem solve the rest of the issue? And thanks for the `lubridate` solution, I'll need to get more familiar with it methinks :)